# Add tab to anchor text with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have something like this ;

```html
<a href="#" class="example">
Link 1
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
Link 2
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
Link 3
</a>
```

I want add tab before anchor text. Like this;

```html
<a href="#" class="example">
  Link 1
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
  Link 2
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
  Link 3
</a>
```

How can I do this with regex?

Comment: Can you elaborate "I want add tab before anchor text"? And your 2nd snippet seams to be exactly the same as first???

Comment: Depends on how input can look like. Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/4QxeAi/1).

Comment: I don't think regex is the way to do this. If there can be nested HTML you'll need to parse it differently

Comment: You should not be using regex for this. You should be using a DOM Parser

Answer (score 1):

### Edit, following the question extension

From his comments, it now appears that the OP targets a more general use, adding `\t`s to *indent all lines* between the opening and closing tag.
Then its time to remember that **regex is not a good way to parse HTML**, as frequently observed here.

But in this yet not too wide context we can propose a solution.
Unless somebody finds a better solution, I don't see a way to do it without 2 nested steps:

```
$updated_text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<a[^>]*>)\s*(.*?)\s*(<\/a>)/s',
    function($matches) {
        return $matches[1]
          . "\n" . preg_replace('/([^\n]+)/', "\t$1", $matches[2])
          . "\n" . $matches[3];
    },
    $text
);
```

Note that, in addition to be a poor way of doing it, it's much time consuming due to the `.*?` (not greedy) quantifier.

---

### Initial answer

Thanks to the @bobblebubble suggestion I just understood what means "I want add tab" (I previously thought only to browser's tabs :).

But I find its solution a bit too general: it'll add tab to *any line* which is not a tag!
I'd prefer to closely look for only `<a>` tags, and only when presented like in the OP's example:

```
$updated_text = preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*>)\s*([^<]*)\s*<\/a>/', '$1\n\t$2</a>', $text);
```

Here is it working: https://regex101.com/r/qo2N22/1.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I want. This is working with text like "Link 1 " . It can work with img tag? Like this ; <a href="#" class="example">
  <img src="bg.jpg">
</a>

Comment: @Samet Yes it can be adapted for many different cases. Regarding the new one in your comment, not sure what you mean exactly: is it that `<img src="bg.jpg">` would appear in a separate line like `Link ...` in your question? If yes, then look at https://regex101.com/r/qo2N22/2.

Comment: I changed your first code : https://regex101.com/r/qo2N22/3                             now I need aply \t all $2 lines. Any idea ?

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for the comment!